# Multi column header in ASP.NET GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a gridview contains 30 columns where few columns i have to set single column on top of it ie i have `Leaf Name,Leaf Code,Leaf Value,Leaf Vendor Code,Leaf Id,Leaf ZOnal,Leaf Leveller` columns  where i need to give single column on top of it as `Leaves Details`.I did following code in rowdatabound with no success, new single column is coming on top of all.Could you please tell me what i did wrong.One more important thing i did is , i set gridview property `PagerSettings  Position top` so that could come on top of grid as index values 1,2,3 etc.

here is my gridview

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grdcell" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="13" DataKeyNames="firstname,location"
                CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" OnPageIndexChanging="grdNewcells_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="grdcell_RowDataBound" >
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Insert" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="insertall" Text="Insert All" onclick="checkAll(this);" runat="server" />
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="insertChk" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></HeaderStyle>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Leaf_NAME" HeaderText="Leaf Name" SortExpression="Leaf_NAME"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Leaf_CODE" HeaderText="Leaf Code" SortExpression="Leaf_CODE"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Leaf_Value" HeaderText="Leaf Value" SortExpression="Leaf_Value"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="LeafVENDOR_CODE" HeaderText="Leaf Vendor Code" SortExpression="LeafVENDOR_CODE"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Leaf_ID" HeaderText="Leaf Id" SortExpression="Leaf_ID"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Leaf_ZOnal" HeaderText="Leaf ZOnal" SortExpression="Leaf_ZOnal"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Leaf_Leveller" HeaderText="Leaf Leveller" SortExpression="Leaf_Leveller"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Loaction" HeaderText="Loaction" SortExpression="Loaction"></asp:BoundField>
```

and the code what i did in `row data bound` as shown below

```
GridViewRow gvRow = e.Row;
                if (gvRow.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
                {
                    if (gvRow.Cells[1].Text == "Leaf_NAME")
                    {
                        gvRow.Cells.Remove(gvRow.Cells[1]);
                        GridViewRow gvHeader = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Insert);
                        TableCell headerCell0 = new TableCell()
                        {
                            Text = "Leaves Details",
                            HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center,
                            RowSpan = 6
                        };

                        gvHeader.Cells.Add(headerCell0);

                        grdcell.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, gvHeader);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: I had the same question as @peter. I had to do something similar in many places in my current work but I use the opposite approach: one single column with a TemplateField containing the subcolumns.

Comment: is it the same question??do you have the code?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I was very confused. I thought that Peter was someone commenting your post, but you commented it yourself.

Comment: I can give you the idea of my code in an answer. By the way, I was also confused by one line of your code: `RowSpan = 6`. Shouldn't it be `ColumnSpan = 6`? And if so, shouldn't you remove 5 of the original cells in the header row?

Comment: i think something wrong in my code, can you post your suggestion code,remember my PagerSettings  Position top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i did it by using following link, but i used gridview row created event

[single column for multiple column](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-GridView-Group-Header-Row-Columns-and-display-Multiple-Columns-under-Single-Column.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In order to "group" several columns in a common header (with subheaders), I use a TemplateField. For 2 subcolumns, it would look like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table runat="server" class="leafCommonHeader" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr class="multiColumnMainHeader">
                <td colspan="2">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="leafHeader" Text="Leaf Details" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr runat="server">
                <td class="leafNameField">
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="leafHeader" OnCommand="gvLeavesColumnSort" CommandArgument="LeafName" Text="Name" />
                </td>
                <td class="leafNameField">
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="leafHeader" OnCommand="gvLeavesColumnSort" CommandArgument="LeafCode" Text="Code" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table runat="server" class="leafCommonItem" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td class="leafNameField">
                    <asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LeafName")) %>' />
                </td>
                <td class="leafCodeField">
                    <asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LeafCode") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The link buttons in the subheaders are there to implement the sort of the subcolumns. I included a few `CssClass` attributes that allow to customize the cells and labels. The CSS classes `leafNameField` and `leafCodeField` can set the with of their column, for example.

Disclaimer: this code was not tested with paging turned on.