# How to display a line follower of a service processes using ASP.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, charts

Please, I need to know how can I make similar to this table in MVC .. my data come from a model as a list of services, each service has a process from a list also, so I need to display a table of the service details and each detail linked to one process at time .. so the sequence of the processes display a line of similar to line chart..  Thank you in advance
[I attached a picture though to show what I meant exactly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gxrU.jpg)

Model:
public partial class ServiceDetail
{
public int ServiceDetailsID { get; set; }
public string ServiceDetailDescription { get; set; }
public int ServiceSequence { get; set; }
public System.TimeSpan TimeToComplete { get; set; }
public int ServiceID { get; set; }
public int ProcessID { get; set; }

```
    public virtual Process Process { get; set; }
    public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
}
```

public partial class Process
{

```
    public Process()
    {
        this.ServiceDetails = new HashSet<ServiceDetail>();
    }

    public int ProcessID { get; set; }
    public string ProcessName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ServiceDetail> ServiceDetails { get; set; }
```

}

Controller:

public ActionResult Display(int? id) // Service's ID passed from another property
{
var serviceDetails = db.ServiceDetails.Where(x => x.ServiceID == id).ToList();

```
        return View(serviceDetails);            
    }
```

Comment: Just based on your description and the image, it is hard to clear what your needs are. Any code provided?

Comment: I update my question by providing some code .. thank you

Comment: Didn't find such table model. Here is a workaround you can try: 1.draw multi column header in GridView ([thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292108/multi-column-header-in-asp-net-gridview), [thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40407883/how-to-achieve-multiple-colspan-and-multiple-header-row-using-asp-net-gridview)); 2.draw the line chart with GDI+.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks